# transfer ajax complete to parent function

Tags: jquery, ajax

i'm trying to figure something out:
I have a function that makes an ajax call. I know I can have onComplete, success.. to execute code after ajax has finished, but what I'm looking for is if I can return something so that code after it would wait for it to finish.

Example:

```
function loadPage(url){
    $.get(url,function(data){
        $("article").html(data);
    })
}
```

The thing is how can I do something like this, maybe by returning something:

```
function loadPage(url){
    $.get(url,function(data){
        $("article").html(data);
    })
    return XXXX;
}
```

So that I could do something different each time function loadPage completes the ajax, like so, or in a similar way to this:

```
loadPage(url).done(otherFunction());
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try this:

```
function loadPage(url){
    return $.get(url,function(data){
        $("article").html(data);
    })
}
```

The jQuery.get() function returns jQuery XHR object which has the done() function.
See the documentaion here [jQuery.get()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/). So just returning the result of the get function will do the job.